# Can't push to forked repo, authentication failed

Tags: git, authentication, fork

So I forked public repo [django-oscar](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.git), and am trying to push my changes for the purposes of a PR.

Every time I try to push to my fork I get this window:

[image]

After entering my github creds I get this error back in my terminal:
`Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.`

1. I know I'm using the correct username and password in the prompt, because I can use those creds to login into github normally via a browser and view the repo.
2. I've used `git remote -v` and checked that I'm targeting the right repo.

I'm on a windows machine.  Any idea on how to resolve this?  Anyone had this before?  My current thought process is that something on the repo is demanding a strange cred, due to the fact I forked it instead of starting a repo on my own.

I've also tried using a personal access token as a password, but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good answers, but in the end the issue was a VSCode extension that was interfering with the push.  I didn't think, this could be the case because I was using the terminal and not the extension, but it was in fact the cause.  I believe it may have been intercepting the call back from the popup window that had me log into in GitHub (..but I can't be sure).  Anyway, after playing around with the extensions setting in VSCode and restarting my machine, the push worked.

Hopefully this may save someone time in the future.

Comment: Which extension was the culprit, and which VSCode extension settings did you modify? (just to avoid https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: @Vonc, I couldn't be specific.  It was last week I resolved this, so I'm a few days past it.  I think what tipped me off was realizing I could push from the source control tab UI in VSCode, but not the terminal.  After which I went on a raid updating and restarting everything I could get my hands on.  I think I actually reinstalled git at one point as well. The true villain here seems to have been lost in the battle fray I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows, make sure you are:

- using the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- setting `git config --global credential.helper manager-core`
- do a `git ls-remote https://<you>@github.com/<you>/<yourRepo>` and enter your credentials there.

Check if a simple `git push` then work.

Once that is done, relaunch GitHub Desktop, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: @JamieMarshall Does it work from command-line?

Comment: You know I didn't test.  I did it through the VSCode terminal. It turned out the extension for GitHub in VSCode was the culprit.   I posted an answer for posterity.